# Changing Tab but URL not change. If URL changed tab not show

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, tabs

The tabs is moving content are changing but url is not changed. here is link t make you clear my problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-tabs-58y4gk

Whenenver I click on tab it changes url (e.g if i  click item 2 url should be /two and other tab also visible).If I set href it navigate other page and Tab is not showing

Comment: what Next.js version are you using?

Comment: @ Asplund
     **"next": "12.1.6"**

Comment: codesandbox does not use Next. In your Next app you need to define a page for each segment (a part in the url) for each tab. See more at [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts)

Comment: yeah, you are right. codesandbox does not use Next. it is just an example. I'm talking about URLs actually

Comment: There is nothing in your code to say the URL should change depending on the tab. Since you are using Next you need to use Next.js router. This means that for each URL segment ("/two" etc.) you need a file called `two.js` in your `pages` directory. Please read the [Next.js docs on routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts) for more information

Comment: Thanks, @Asplund for reviewing my code. I make it dynamic not a page routing. My code is just an example it's not an actual code.

Comment: I know it's an example, I used your example to try and explain that you need to use Next.js router. You can use dynamic routes in Next.js, refer to the [docs on dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change url, you have to use routing tools like location.href or react-router-dom library, etc... There is no routing related codes.

And there is no page to render when you used the href.

Use react-router-dom

```
<Routes>
  // Render One.jsx when you access to /one path.
  <Route path="/one" element={<One />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: `react-router-dom` does not work on Next.js since Next has its own routing system